# Take indices of non zero elements of matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I create matrix "adjacency_matrix" with following code:

```
n = int(input())

# Initialize matrix
adjacency_matrix = []
  
# For user input
for i in range(ROWS):       
    a =[]
    for j in range(COLUMNS):   
        a.append(int(input()))
        adjacency_matrix.append(a)
```

I want to save indices of non zero elements of above matrix.

for example n = 3;

```
adjacency_matrix =

2 3 0

0 0 1

1 5 0
```

I want to save rows of non zero element in "li_r":

```
li_r = [0 0 1 2 2]
```

and save columns of non zero element in "li_c":

```
li_c = [0 1 2 0 1]
```

**My goal is** take (0,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,0) (2,1) as row and column of non-zero element
and give them to **g.addEdge(u,v)** in my code, I mean I want to have

```
g.addEdge(0,0)
g.addEdge(0,1)
g.addEdge(1,2)
g.addEdge(2,0)
g.addEdge(2,1)
```

I write this code, but not work:

```
for i in range(n):

li_r = [];

li_c = []

for j in range(n):

if adjacency_matrix[i][j]!=0:

li_r.append(i)

li_c.append(j)

for i in range(len(li_r)):
    for j in range(len(li_c)):
        g.addEdge(li_r[i], li_c[j])
```

I new in Python and if possible, help me and rewrite my code.

Comment: You need to be using `numpy` for this kind of thing.  It can return the set of non-zero indices in a single statement.

Comment: @TimRoberts, You mean I can't write my code with for loops without use numpy?

Comment: In your first code, the index of the **adjacency_matrix.append(a)** code looks wrong. I think it's right to move 4 spaces forward.

Comment: Of course you can, but it would be easier and much more efficient with `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this list comprehension. It returns a list of positions (x,y) and you can iterate over each one and insert them into g.addEdge()

```
adjacency_matrix =[[2,3,0],[0,0,1],[1,5,0]]
pos = [(count1, count2) for count1, lst in enumerate(adjacency_matrix) for count2, num in enumerate(lst)  if num != 0]
```

output

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

**g.addEdge()**

```
for i in pos:
    g.addEdge(*i)
```

Comment: How can insert them into g.addEdge()?

Comment: You can iterate over pos and preform g.addEdge (updated answer). Do you want to update the pos list values with g.addEdge or simply iterate over it and preform a function on each item?

Comment: How can I iterate over pos and take g.addEdge(0,0), ...?
Can change pos and from the beginning, I get g.addEdge(count1,count2)?

Comment: i updated the answer, is it not working? ```for i in pos:
    g.addEdge(*i)```

Comment: When I use for loop to define adjacency_matrix, pos is not work.

Comment: no. Adjency matrix is not going to be changed. Why would you have a loop on it. Print out pos, that has all the posistions on it. Then you can iterate on **pos** and preform g.addEdge(*i)